# sqlalchemy how to get list of data instead of list of sqlalchemy.util._collections.result

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table of file information in my DB
I am trying to query and return the file_path column of the result as list of string.

My code looks like below

```
path_found = session.query(db.file_table.path).filter([filters]).all()
```

It returns a list of sqlalchemy.util._collections.result instead of list of string.

Is there any way to get the query result as a list of string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = [str(path) for path in path_found]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Example Code:

```
query = session.query(Region.name).all()

query = map(lambda t: t[0], query)
query = list(query)

print(query)
```